# AWS Glue Visual ETL mapping

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I'm trying to load the CSV data from the AWS data catalog into the RDS PostgreSQL database.
I don't see the actual mapping options in the Apply Mapping node in AWS Glue.
It's a very basic job, what am I doing wrong? The names of the attributes in the source and target datasources are the same. The only difference is that my postgreSQL table has a primary key ID.

[Apply mapping node, where is mapping?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xg9Nh.png)

[the target postgre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXelb.png)

Thanks in advance for your help

Tried to change the data types.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question completely. The source keys in "Apply Mapping" are the columns from CSV data. The target keys will be the column names that you will map in PostgreSQL table. If your column names are different in PostgreSQL table, then you change the target keys in "Apply Mapping" section. 

The target keys and data types can be modified also under the "script" tab.

Comment: I'm expecting too see column mapping where I can map my source columns (from CSV) to target (Postgre)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution I think, If I set up both target and source as Glue catalog then I can perform column mapping.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).